# How to unzip an AES encrypted zip file on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, aes, unzip

In my current iPhone project I need to decrypt zip files which have been encrypted using AES 256 method either on a Mac with StuffIt Engine or on Windows with WinZip.

I tried to use ZipArchive (based on MiniZip) but it doesn't work. Anyone knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up buying a license for [IPWorks ZIP library](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/zip/) which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Added AES encryption support to Minizip contrib:
https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip

Answer (score 1):

I just encrypted a zip file on my Mac using WinZip Pro Version 10.5.6553. 256-bit AES was selected as the Encryption method in settings. I transferred the file to the iPhone. In files I opened it, it asked for the password and decrypted it with no problem. Assuming the WinZip Pro App was working correctly, then the standard files app on the iPhone can decrypt zip files encrypted with 256-bit AES encryption. (iOS 16.6.1, just prior to the 17 release)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to port (include) InfoZip sources, they are compatible with such encryption style.
However, you should also check if the license for InfoZip is adequate for your circumstances.

Comment: No. This won't help. As far as I am aware, InfoZip does not do WinZip AES Encryption.