# How do I create a zip file with AES 256 encryption in iOS?

Tags: ios, zip, aes, winzip

I would like to know is there any open source library that able to zip a file with AES 256 password on iOS ?

I google around. There is AES 256 encryption (but not zipped). and there is zipping library (but not AES256 encrypted). I m curious that why there does not have AES encryption + zip together while there has both free libraries to do so.

I hope someone could give me some more ideas on zip + AES 256 encryption stuff.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe this discussion can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493733/how-to-unzip-an-aes-encrypted-zip-file-on-the-iphone