# How to unzip AES encrypted files in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, zip, aes

I'm a beginner in Objective-C and need your help.

In iOS I need to unzip files which have been encrypted using AES 256 method.

In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10489305/2822169 Nathan Moinvaziri writes about using this library: https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip

I'm trying to do this:

```
#import "unzip.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *zipPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.zip"];   // this file exists there 100%

    unzFile *uf = unzOpen64((__bridge const void *)(zipPath));  // but here uf returns 0x00000000
    unzOpenCurrentFilePassword(uf, (__bridge const void *)(@"myPassword"));
}
```

Tell me please what is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be best Library for [unZip.](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive)

DownLoad it and add it to your project and,

```
#import "ZipArchive.h" // in your ".m" file
```

And write following code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *basepath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"resources.zip"]];
    [self.responseData  writeToFile:basepath  atomically:YES];

    ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    if( [za UnzipOpenFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",basepath]] )
    {
        BOOL ret = [za UnzipFileTo:[GeneralClass getDocumentDirectory]  overWrite:YES];
        if(!ret)
            NSLog(@"problem while loading data..");
        [za UnzipCloseFile];
    }

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:basepath error:NULL];

    basepath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"response.txt"]];
    NSString* response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:basepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSMutableDictionary *detailRequestData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    detailRequestData = [response JSONValue];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:basepath error:NULL];

 NSLog(@"I Got Data%@", detailRequestData); /// see in consol
```

Comment: Thank you. But are you sure that this Library supports AES encryption in zip files?